# как получить аргументы URL?

Tags: php

Такая беда, ссылка выглядит вот так `<a href=?page=2`

после отработки .htaccess, ссылка получается не `page=2`, а просто `домен/2`

Если вытаскивать так `print_r($_GET);` то такой get параметр он не видит.

Если так echo `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`, то видит, и можно достать её с помощью explode и потом по числовым ключам найти эту страницу, но проблема состоит в том, что если перед этим аргументом, будет ещё аргументы, то уже нужный ключ будет стоять в другом месте, а как сделать, что бы всегда можно было получить нужный ключ?

Вот так нормально `shop/2/`

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => shop
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 
)
```

Но будут случаи, когда в урле, будет только `shop/?sort=asc`

Тогда **explode** будет работать некорректно, как быть в таких случаях, проверять количество аргументов, перед разбивокой?

Или искать регулярками карман, в котором есть только цифры?

Comment: кажется с htaccess все должно быть  наоборот, а если нет, то не понятно зачем

Comment: @DivMan _Или искать регулярками карман, в котором есть только цифры?_ - ну а почему бы и нет? Регулярки вроде бы прекрасно справляются с маршрутами.

Comment: @teran почему наоборот? Это что бы облегчить обработку раздела?

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` не поможет?